# Mongodb aggregation build output with multidimention array

Tags: php, mongodb, multidimensional-array, aggregation-framework

I need some help with MongoDB aggregate to get an output like I want.
The goal is to have the result directly with the request without using php to build multidimensional array.

*Modules Collection exemple:*

```
{
   _id: ObjectID('111111111111111111111'),
   name: 'module1'
},
{
   _id: ObjectID('111111111111111111112'),
   name: 'module2'
}
```

*Controllers Collection exemple:*

```
{
   _id: ObjectID('22222222222222222221'),
   name: 'controller1'
},
{
   _id: ObjectID('22222222222222222223'),
   name: 'controller3'
}
```

*Actions Collection exemple:*

```
{
   _id: ObjectID('333333333333333333331'),
   name: 'action1'
},
{
   _id: ObjectID('333333333333333333332'),
   name: 'action2'
}
```

*Resources Collection exemple:*

```
{
   _id: ObjectID('555555555555555555511'),
   module_id: ObjectID('111111111111111111111'),
   controller_id: ObjectID('22222222222222222221'),
   action_id: ObjectID('333333333333333333331'),
},
{
   _id: ObjectID('555555555555555555512'),
   module_id: ObjectID('111111111111111111112'),
   controller_id: ObjectID('22222222222222222221'),
   action_id: ObjectID('333333333333333333332'),
},{
   _id: ObjectID('55555555555555555553'),
   module_id: ObjectID('111111111111111111111'),
   controller_id: ObjectID('22222222222222222223'),
   action_id: ObjectID('333333333333333333332'),
},
{
   _id: ObjectID('555555555555555555514'),
   module_id: ObjectID('111111111111111111112'),
   controller_id: ObjectID('22222222222222222221'),
   action_id: ObjectID('333333333333333333331'),
},
```

Then I use aggregate to retrieve resource name.

```
db.resources.aggregate(
        {
            { '$lookup' => { 'from' => 'modules', 'localField' => 'module_id', 'foreignField' => '_id', 'as' => 'module' } },
            { '$unwind' => '$module'],
            { '$lookup' => { 'from' => 'controllers', 'localField' => 'controller_id', 'foreignField' => '_id', 'as' => 'controller' } },
            { '$unwind' => '$controller'},
            { '$lookup' => { 'from' => 'actions', 'localField' => 'action_id', 'foreignField' => '_id', 'as' => 'action' } },
            { '$unwind' => '$action'},
            { '$project' => { '_id' => 1, 'module' => '$module.name', 'controller' => '$controller.name', 'action' => '$action.name'}}
        }
    )
```

*result :*

```
[
    ["_id"] => ObjectID('555555555555555555511'),
    ["module"] => 'module1',
    ["controller"] => 'controller1',
    ["action"] => 'action1',
],
[
    ["_id"] => ObjectID('555555555555555555512'),
    ["module"] => 'module2',
    ["controller"] => 'controller1',
    ["action"] => 'action2',
],
[
    ["_id"] => ObjectID('555555555555555555513'),
    ["module"] => 'module1',
    ["controller"] => 'controller2',
    ["action"] => 'action2',
],
[
    ["_id"] => ObjectID('555555555555555555514'),
    ["module"] => 'module2',
    ["controller"] => 'controller1',
    ["action"] => 'action1',
]
```

This is the result what I want :
(I spend a lot of time to use $group but i don't find solution)

```
[
    ['module1' => 
        ['controller1' => 
            ['action1'] => '555555555555555555511'
        ],
        ['controller2']
            ['action2'] => '555555555555555555513'
    ],            
    ['module2' =>
        ['controller1' =>
            ['action2'] => '555555555555555555512',
            ['action1'] => '555555555555555555514'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Is it possible to get this result ? and how I can do this without using php to build this array ?

Comment: What do you expect in the result when Resources Collection have multiple objects for the same module-controller-action combination, e.g. `{
   _id: 1,
   module_id: 1,
   controller_id: 1,
   action_id: 1
},{
   _id: 2,
   module_id: 1,
   controller_id: 1,
   action_id: 1
}`?

Comment: Each object can contain only one module, one controller, one action, and there is no duplicate. I would like the result to be grouped by concerving the tree by name not by _id. With your exemple this I would this result : { "module_name": { "controller_name": { "action_name": _id  }}}

Comment: Fair enough, assuming you have a unique index to ensure no duplicates. The thing is, aggregation does not support dynamic fields. You can group-push results, but it would look more like `[{'name'=>'module1', controllers=>[{'name'=>'controller1', 'actions'=>[{'name'=>'action1', 'value'=>'555555555555555555511'}]]]`